# php dynamic date for user

Tags: php, date, datetime

Hello to all the experts here.

I have a conceptual question that I can use some help with.

In our site, we allow users to join a group for a specific amount of time. So there is a group that has activities outlined as follows week0day1, week0day4, week1day2, week1day5, week2day3. 
In these groups we allow users to join and leave as they would like so week0day1 is not necessarily the same for each user.

I have worked out which week a user is currently in by looking at the date that they joined the group and then doing some math from there, that's not my problem. My issue comes from how I translate which day of the week an activity on a day like week0day4 would fall out on.

I thought about using the day of the week the user joined the group as an offset but I am not sure if that is the correct way to deal with this as there might be issues when the offset creates a situation where the calculated day of the week is not actually a valid weekday.

Can anyone recommend a better solution?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't reinvent the wheel, this already exists in PHP

http://php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php

Given a date you can work out the Day, Tuesday, Wednesday etc. Its always better to work in the standard date time classes.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, can you point me in a more specific direction with this datetime class? That was the first place I looked...

Comment: ok so I think that I would use the datediff method for calculating, but I dont see how that would help me in translating what day of the week week0day4 would fall out on for two users that joined the same group on different days..

Comment: Well you should design your system better for starters. If you know what date Week0 Day0 is then you can construct a data object with day, month, year and then simply get the day of the week out of the datetime object.

Comment: i don't think the system is design badly, the point is that week0day0 can be different for two different users. Of course I know when week0day0 is that is logged in the database according to each user, and I know how to pull the weekday from a date. It seems to me that I should be going a datediff between today and the joined_date of the group to determine if there is an activity today...Is that what you mean?

Comment: With the date time class you can do anything like that. Diffs, add or whatever. As long as you can get dates into that object then there are lots of different functions. r.e. design, why not store everything as a date and then derive week0day0 from that... or store both?

Comment: I do store everything in the db as a date, and I don't need to derive the week0day0 because I store it as metadata. The issue is deriving future dates from week0day0 (because I have that).

Comment: Ok, so you should be able to add weeks to date objects and do "date arithmetic" to work it out quite easily with that class.